# Simulated Data and the Probit Model in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a very simple question about using simulated data in R with the probit model.  Any method I have used to generate data and then use that data to run the probit model returns warning about perfect fits:  Specifically:

```
Warning message:
In glm.fit(x = X, y = Y, weights = weights, start = start, etastart = etastart, :
  fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Is there some method to generate data for this type of model that would not provide this error?  Whenever I try to use the glm() command with probit, I get the warning.  I have tried a large number of different set.seed() values and each one still returns the warning.  I have also tried several different methods (and values) as well, but none work.  Here is sample code:

```
n <- 1000
set.seed(1211)
b.true1 <- c(-1, 2, .8)
X1 <- cbind(rnorm(n, 1.5, 2), rnorm(n, -2, 1.3))
eps.t1 <- rnorm(n)
y.star1 <- b.true1[1] + X1%*%b.true1[2:3] + eps.t1
y1 <- ifelse(y.star1<=0, 0, 1)
prob2 <- glm(y1~X1, family=binomial(link="probit"))
```

So the two questions from this are:

1. Should this be a major concern?  I know that this could make the standard errors too large, but I didn't know if I can still use the results from the model given the warning.
2. Is there a way to generate sample data for a probit model without getting this warning?

The simulated data is being used to test a complex log likelihood function that I need to make sure is coded properly.  If these warnings are causing the probit results to be invalid, then it won't do any good to use this data for testing the likelihood function!

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: This is better suited for http://www.crossvalidated.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, I wonder why you take such high differences. If you look at y.star1 (which is the probit values), those values have a huge range (going form -10 to 14). This will lead to the warning, as the rounding will make the probability responses 0 or 1.

Taking care the results aren't as extreme as those, is all you need to get rid of the warning. Making the differences in the means of X1 smaller and the b.true1 coefficients closer to 0 helps :

```
b.true1 <- c(-1, 1, .8)
X1 <- cbind(rnorm(n, 1.5, 2), rnorm(n, -1, 1.3))
```

gives no warning, and still shows a rather well distinction in the data :

```
hist(predict(prob2,type="response"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  I had started from simulated code that I knew worked in Matlab and was trying to make it work in R.  I had other code that used different values for beta and still got the error, so I thought it was something with my set up rather than the coefficient values.